# How to define a custom tag that filter each list on type base

Tags: c#, mustache

I am trying to filter my list of users on basis of type 
    like users where type is admin

In .net core 2.0 mustache-sharp tried condition based tag but not sure how to do this.

I want to define a tag like

```
{{#each users}}
{{#type admin}}
{{FirstName}}
{{/type}}
{{/each}}
```

and that shows result only for admin type users
    like

```
John  
Mark
```